# Video shot from Android phone has to be streamed to JSP page via WiFi

Tags: java, jsp, video-streaming

My aim is to live stream video shot from Android phone to JSP page and show it in a media player.

How can I receive data from phone and show it in JSP real-time? Is there any API that I can use?

Comment: **Spydroid-IP Camera [link](http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/) and Wowza Streaming Server [link](http://www.wowza.com/) did the job.**